# Is there a C++ library I can use to stitch together 16-bit images?

Tags: library, c++, images, image-processing, stitching

I am working on a C++ project where I need to stitch together multiple 16-bit images which overlap horizontally and vertically, and then save the stitched image. Is there a library which I can use to accomplish this task?

I have tried to use an OpenCV Stitcher object to no success because the following exception was thrown:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.0.1) /home/rar/opencv_build/opencv/modules/stitching/src/exposure_compensate.cpp:317: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _image.type() == CV_8UC3 in function 'apply'
```

Here is my code snippet which performs the stitching:

```
// vector containing 16-bit images
std::vector<cv::UMat> images;

cv::Ptr<cv::Stitcher> stitcher = cv::Stitcher::create();
cv::UMat stitched;
cv::Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(images, stitched);  // Performs the image stitching and outputs a status
```

Other people seem to have faced the same problem as I have [https://answers.opencv.org/question/34795/stitching-16bits-greyscale-images/]

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 types of 16-bit images: Grayscale and RGB.

The company I work for has an imaging SDK that supports both types and can stitch 2 (or more) images using C/C++ code like this:

```
BITMAPHANDLE smallBmp1 = {0}, smallBmp2 = {0}, bigBmp = {0};
int ByteOrder = ORDER_GRAY; // change to ORDER_BGR if images are color instead of grayscale
//load 2 input images
L_LoadBitmap(imageFile1, &smallBmp1, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, 16, ByteOrder, 0, 0);
L_LoadBitmap(imageFile2, &smallBmp2, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, 16, ByteOrder, 0, 0);
//ensure both bitmaps have same view perspective (orientation)
L_ChangeBitmapViewPerspective(0, &smallBmp1, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, TOP_LEFT);
L_ChangeBitmapViewPerspective(0, &smallBmp2, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, TOP_LEFT);
//prepare big image to hold result
L_CreateBitmap(&bigBmp, sizeof BITMAPHANDLE, TYPE_CONV, 
   BITMAPWIDTH(&smallBmp1) + BITMAPWIDTH(&smallBmp2),       //width is total width
   max(BITMAPHEIGHT(&smallBmp1), BITMAPHEIGHT(&smallBmp2)), //height is larger of the two
   16, ByteOrder, 0, TOP_LEFT, 0, 0);
//stitch 2 images on big image
L_CombineBitmap(&bigBmp, 0, 0, BITMAPWIDTH(&smallBmp1), BITMAPHEIGHT(&smallBmp1), &smallBmp1, 0, 0, CB_OP_ADD | CB_DST_0 | CB_RAWCOMBINE, 0);
L_CombineBitmap(&bigBmp, BITMAPWIDTH(&smallBmp1), 0, BITMAPWIDTH(&smallBmp2), BITMAPHEIGHT(&smallBmp2), &smallBmp2, 0, 0, CB_OP_ADD | CB_DST_0 | CB_RAWCOMBINE, 0);
//save the result
L_SaveBitmap(outputFile, &bigBmp, FILE_TIFLZW, 16, 0, 0);
//cleanup
L_FreeBitmap(&smallBmp1);
L_FreeBitmap(&smallBmp2);
L_FreeBitmap(&bigBmp);
```

The function that performs the actual stitching [is documented here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/main/api/l-combinebitmap.html).

If you would like to try the toolkit, there’s [a free evaluation edition you can download here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main).